# How to restore groups and sudo rights for my linux user?

Tags: linux, sudo

Recently I accidentally executed the `usermod` command to add a group to my user; unfortunately I forgot the `-a` operator, so the command removed all the other groups from my user.

After next login I recognized that I cannot `sudo` any more.

[After research](https://www.tecmint.com/usermod-command-examples/), I restored the `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` files from my backup. All groups for my user got successfully restored and now look like this:

```
[tobias@asterix ~]$ id tobias
uid=1000(tobias) gid=1001(tobias) groups=1001(tobias),0(root),995(audio),991(lp),1000(autologin)
```

Now I did re-login, but still the same error message:

```
[tobias@asterix ~]$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for tobias: 
tobias is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I checked the `/ect/sudoers`, which on the first hand didn't get changed at all in the past, and it already does contain the following line:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

If I am not mistaken, as my user is already part of the `root` group, everything should actually be fine.

Maybe somebody can give me a hint of how to completely restore the setup of my system to original behavior?

Comment: Do you make regular backups of your `/etc`-directory? This seems a typical backup-and-restore use case... :-#

Comment: I do make regular backups of my system, but did never restore anything so far except the two files mentioned above by manually copying them in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown *sudoers* entry isn't for a group; it's for the "root" *user*. A group entry would begin with a `%`.

If you know the root password, use `su` to switch to the root user, and from there you can fix group memberships and/or add sudoers entries for yourself or whatever group.

If not, then you'll have to use [recovery mode, or a live CD](https://superuser.com/questions/380851/how-to-restore-sudo-privilege-with-linux-live-cd?rq=1). (You can try booting with the kernel option "systemd.debug-shell" to get a recovery shell on <kbd>Alt+F9</kbd>.)

In the future, use `gpasswd --add` / `gpasswd --delete` to change your group membership instead of using *usermod*.

Answer (score 0):

You are not a member of the right SUDO group, but you are a member of the unix group “root”. So, you may be able to write every file or folder with the rights ---rwx---.

So, you may be to able to create a security privilege escalation by rewriting or changing any file or folder group writable.